# How do I add an existing paragraph field to another content type programmatically

Tags: 8, nodes, paragraphs

I have a paragraph field that is already used in a content type. I need to add that paragraph field to another content type using the same field that I was using in the previous content type. How do I do that?

Comment: I'd recommend adding the field in config, this means configure in UI (see the answer from @ssibal) and export the YAML files. How to add bundle fields programmatically see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/222296/47547

Answer (score 1):

Should be the same as with any other fields:

1. You go `Structure/Content Types/MyContentType`
2. Re-use an existing field: `Entity Reference Revisions: ..`
3. You click `Save and continue` and you apply your settings.

Comment: I need a programmatical way to do this

Comment: Could you please extend your question with the exact use case why you need that? Would help us to find the right way, because this part can be risky.