# Hook for Node Add Field?

Tags: 8, hooks

For my use case, this question revolves around the entities `node` and `paragraph`.

Fields in my projects are created under the following structure:

- content_h2
- paragraph_h2
- content_p
- paragraph_p
- ...

etc...

For example, I'd like to create `field_name` on a node, check if it exists in paragraph entity storage and if not create it. And the other way around.

I've had some success but it seems like more coding than needed.

**Does a hook exist for node add field?**

Example form class: `field-ui-field-storage-add-form`.

Comment: Aren’t storage and instances stored differently for different entities? I don’t see user fields for nodes or paragraphs and Vice versa.

Comment: @Kevin precisely, so OP wants to avoid two of the same.

Comment: This looks like it is about the config entity FieldStorageConfig, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222260/add-content-type-field-programmatically

Comment: which like any entity has plenty of CRUD hooks, see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/group/entity_crud/8.7.x

Answer (score 1):

By the way, all the hooks are [listed here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/group/hooks/8.7.x) there doesn't appear one that fits the task tho.

You can always add a custom validation to the field add form.

```
/*
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()
 */
function mymodule_form_field_ui_field_storage_add_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_custom_add_field_validation';
}

/*
 * Custom Validate Callback
 */
function mymodule_custom_add_field_validation(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // the code that performs the check
  // if (......) {
  //   $form_state->setErrorByName('label',
  //     t('This field already exists in another entity'));
  // }
}
```