# How to create a term reference field programmatically

Tags: entities, 9

I need to add a taxonomy reference field to a node bundle, programmatically.

I found a couple examples here, but one actually is incorrectly titled and is about creating a from field for it, and the other is from 2012.

I have tried the following, based on the couple of suggested examples I found, and a further suggestion that one use the field/field storage export as a guide.

When it runs, it silently fails. The field is not created, nor is there an error thrown.

```
use Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition;
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig;
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig;

$handler_settings = [
      'target_bundles' => [
        '<vid>' => '<vid>'
      ],
      'sort' => [
        'field' => 'name',
        'direction' => 'asc',
      ],
      'auto_create' => FALSE,
      'auto_create_bundle' => '',
    ];
    

$fields['<field_my_field>'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ->setLabel(t('<My Field>'))
  ->setDescription(t(''))
  ->setRequired(TRUE)
  ->setSetting('target_type', 'taxonomy_term')
  ->setSetting('handler', 'default')
  ->setSetting('handler_settings', $handler_settings)
  ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
  ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
    'label' => 'hidden',
    'type' => '<vid>',
    'weight' => 0,
  ])
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
    'weight' => 5,
    'match_operator' => 'CONTAINS',
  ])
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
  ->setCardinality(1);
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you have this code, but you're not actually saving anything here so that could be the problem.

Comment: It's called in a Ajax callback from a form.BaseFieldDefinition::create shouldn't need a save

Comment: You can't save this code, it is for adding a base field to an entity type and it needs to be run either in the entity class itself or in hook_entity_base_field_info().

Comment: If you want to add a bundle field to a content type you have to save it as configuration, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222260/add-content-type-field-programmatically

Comment: It says that the easiest way is to use config, but that isn't an option in my use case, and I'm assuming that when adding a field via the UI, it's doing it without config.

Comment: When you configure a field in UI it is saved as configuration when you submit the form.

Comment: I see. I note that the end of the example you cite provides a code example for both creating the storage and mapping that storage to a bundle. Do you feel that it's valid?

Comment: Installing the field storage via the module config folder is a practical thing to do, when you uninstall the module the storage gets removed automatically, otherwise you would need to program an uninstall hook. For the installed module you then can map that field storage to any content type by saving a field config.

Comment: Right. It makes sense, unfortunately. My context here is a process for taking critical data from a node bundle text field, scrubbing it, creating a new vocabulary, mapping it to the new terms, deleting the old field, adding a reference field with the original field machine name, and populating the fields. Doing the removal and resurrection of the field via config would be problematic, but it is what it is. 
Please paste your comment with the link as the answer, and thanks!