# How to enable a field programmatically

Tags: entities

I've created a field programmatically :

```
$field_storage = FieldStorageConfig::create(
  array('entity_type' => 'node', 'field_name' => 'field_desc', 'type' => 'string'));
$field_storage->save();
$field = FieldConfig::create(
  array('entity_type' => 'node', 'field_name' => 'field_desc', 'bundle' => 'mybundle', 'settings' => array('handler' => 'default', 'handler_settings' => array())));
$field->save();
```

But the field is disabled by default when I access to "manage form display".

My question is : how can I enable the field programatically?

thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You enable the field by adding a widget to the default form display mode:

```
$display_repository = \Drupal::service('entity_display.repository');

// Assign widget settings for the default form mode.
$display_repository->getFormDisplay('node', 'mybundle')
  ->setComponent('field_desc', [
    'type' => 'string_textfield',
  ])
  ->save();
```

See [Add content type field programmatically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222260/add-content-type-field-programmatically)

Comment: Another hint for things like this is to look at the core kernel and functional tests. You can learn a lot from the `setUp()` methods.